# Rails link_to, jumping 50 pixels before an anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, slim-lang

I have buttons in my rails app's navbar which link to divs within the page. The links work fine but since I'm using a bootstrap navbar that stays anchored to the top, the navbar cuts off the top of the div. Right now my rails link to looks like this

```
li = link_to new_family_path(anchor: "testimonialsSection")
  span Testimonials
```

How I can edit this to take me 50 pixels before the testimonialsSection?

Comment: Does not Bootstrap explicitly tell us to add `padding-top: 70px;` or something to body tag when using a fixed navbar?

Comment: Mind those big red alert boxes in the documentation when using bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top